# How to initialize the key field of a map with the use of an iterator?

Tags: c++, string, maps

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cout<<" String : ";
    std::getline(std::cin,s);
    std::map<std::string,std::string> mapa;
    std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator it(mapa.begin());
    it->first = s;
    it->second = s;
    std::cout << it->second << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why can I not initialize the key field of a map (it->first=s does not work) but the second field does work?. And what is the solution?

Comment: The map uses the value of the key to organize itself. How would it ensure its order isn't broken if you could modify things willy-nilly?

Comment: Let's begin with your map being empty.

Comment: Ok I get what but I am adding a new information to the map, why would that make a problem to the order of the map and by the way this is what the compiler says:

Comment: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'const std::basic_string<char>' and 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}')

Comment: @DimChtz but why does then the second field work if I give the strings value

Comment: At this point `it` is actually `mapa.end()`. Btw, this is not how we use maps.

Comment: You aren't inserting information. Iterators are an interface for traversing existing key-value pairs, not add them. You modify the value on a non-exiting pair. It's just buggy and likely to break.

Comment: Just to demonstrate this is broken code, here it is, crashing http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b77acd73f7557a34

Comment: Ok, I think i get what the problem is, but how to solve it without using initialization lists

Comment: Use the [proper API](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). In this case it would be `insert` or `emplace`.

Comment: **Thank you all, I understand now**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can I not initialize the key field of a map (it->first=s does not
>   work) but the second field does work?. And what is the solution?

You have the answer in your question itself. `std::map` maps a key to a value. That means, at the time of creation itself you need to set both(key and value).

`it->first=s;` This will not compile, because you haven't mentioned, what is the key for.

`it->second=s;` This is a UB. Since you haven't mentioned the key with it.

> std::map is a sorted associative container that contains key-value
>   pairs with unique keys. Keys are sorted by using the comparison
>   function Compare.

Therefore, in order to do the comparison and put in the correct position in the data structure, it needs both informations together.

The solutions are:

- `mapa[key] = value;` using `(operator[])`. You can use the same to access the values in the map  directly by their corresponding key.
- `mapa.emplace("key", "value");`
- `mapa.insert ( std::pair<std::string, std::string>("key", "value") );`
- `mapa.insert ( std::make_pair("key", "value") );`
- `std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator it(mapa.begin());`
  `mapa.insert (it, std::pair<std::string, std::string>("key", "value"));`